How to add version to index.html during ng build?
When I build an Angular 17+ project using ng build, I would like the version from package.json to be inserted into the HTML <head>. Something like:
 <meta name="version" content="1.0.1" />

I know the Angular version gets inserted into the <app-root> web component, but that's not what I'm after--I want the project version to be injected.

I don't know if Angular CLI offers this, but surely it would be fairly straightforward to put e.g. <meta name="version" content="<<some placeholder>>"> into the src/index.html, then replace it in dist/index.html with the relevant value using a postbuild script.

I don't have an answer for this however you could look into this GitHub issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7824. There seems to be a script you can add/run before the ng build to achieve desired functionality.


Create a Node.js script to read the version number and inject it into index.html.



const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const packageJson = require('./package.json');

// Read version number from package.json
const version = packageJson.version;

// Define the path to index.html
const indexPath = path.join(__dirname, 'dist/your-angular-project/index.html');

// Read index.html content
fs.readFile(indexPath, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    // Create the meta tag with the version number
    const metaTag = `<meta name="version" content="${version}">`;

    // Inject the meta tag into the <head> section
    const result = data.replace(
        '</head>',
        `${metaTag}\n</head>`
    );

    // Write the modified content back to index.html
    fs.writeFile(indexPath, result, 'utf8', (err) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log('Version number injected successfully!');
    });
});





Modify the angular.json file to include the custom script after the build process.



{
  ...
  "projects": {
    "your-angular-project": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            ...
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              ...
              "scripts": [
                {
                  "input": "inject-version.js",
                  "bundleName": "inject-version"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}




According to this:
https://angular.dev/reference/configs/workspace-config
...the "scripts" part of the configuration section is where you can inject additional scripts into the final build, so I'm not sure that's the right place to invoke this. I'm not terribly familiar with the details of the Angular config options, admittedly.
